# iOS UIButton text display incorrect

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I am working on an application to learn iOS programming, it's a simple calculator app.

The nib file shows all of the button displaying correctly:

[image: nib file]

Whereas when the app is run in the simulator the buttons on the last row are not displayed correctly.

[image: simulator]

All buttons have the state config as default, and a plain font set to 15 points system bold.

I have tried lots of settings for the properties of the UI buttons to no effect, and it seems to only effect the bottom row.

Any ideas ?

Comment: does a button have backgound image?

Comment: All button attributes the same?

Comment: No background image, all attributes the same.

Comment: Did you ever happen to find an answer to this? I've been having the exact same problem and can't seem to find the answer anywhere!

Comment: Nope, I have even tried to set the button text programmatically after the uiviewcontroller is created, but alas, no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I've found is that if I disable Autolayout, it fixes the problem. However, the buttons lose their positioning on the screen. But when I re-enable Autolayout it re-arranges the button as intended and the text on the UIButton is also restored. Again, I am also not sure how this works but it is a workaround for iOS 6.0. I have not tried adding new buttons and observing whether this fix is persistent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm had a simular issue, I fixed this by disabling Autolayout.
Click on Storyboard. On the IdentityTab, disable "Use Layout".

(Honesty I don't know why, this works)